# Custom profile/services in Bluetooth low energy

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Please don't mind my naivety. I am new to developing for Bluetooth Low Energy devices. My recent application needs to interact with the Mi Band 2 device. Got some guidance for connecting with the generic services from https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services

Now I need to read and work with the Custom Services of the device's BLE Stack.
Is there any way to find out which Custom service is meant for which purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Custom services are custom, and not standardised. Anyone can design their own custom service and they don't need to document it.

Comment: I understand your point. But is there any way to know the purpose of the custom service?

Comment: What I would do is to look for the UUIDs of the services implemented on the Mi Band 2, and google them. You can get the UUID using apps like [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en). If you don't find anything, then you need to somehow reverse engineer them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will give it a try